# UDF linked to external workbook

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create a UDF using the SUMPRODUCT function which will reference data in an external closed workbook and return a value based on a couple of different criteria.

The reason I am tyring to do this is because some of the formula in the file while using the SUMPRODUCT feature could end up quite long.

So far I have come up with the following and appear to be just getting a #value error returning.

```
Public Function ReceiptTotal(Criteria1 As Variant, Criteria2 As Variant, Criteria3 As Variant) As Variant

Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim Criteria1Column As Range
Dim Criteria2Column As Range
Dim Criteria3Column As Range
Dim ResultColumn As Range
Dim LastRow As Long


Set wbk = Workbooks("J:\Users\Sarah\New Cash Sheet Ideas\[Receipt Log Test.xlsm]")
Set wks = wbk.Worksheets("1819")

    With wbk
    With wks
    LastRow = wbk.wks.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set Criteria1Column = wbk.wks.Range("E5:E" & LastRow)  'Criteria1Column = Bank Account
    Set Criteria2Column = wbk.wks.Range("F5:F" & LastRow)  'Criteria2Column = Receipt Type
    Set Criteria3Column = wbk.wks.Range("J5:J" & LastRow)  'Criteria3Column = Date
    Set ResultColumn = wbk.wks.Range("H5:H" & LastRow)     'ResultColumn = Receipt Value

ReceiptTotal = [SUMPRODUCT((ResultColumn) * (Criteria1Column = Criteria1) * (CriteriaColumn2 = Criteria2) * (CriteriaColumn3 = Criteria3)]

End With
End With

End Function
```

I would really appreciate if someone can advise where I am going wrong.

Comment: Maybe `worksheetfunction.sumproduct(...)`?

Comment: So many issues: 1) VBA Evaluate doesn't work on closed workbooks (though SumProduct as a cell formula will) 2) the string you pass to Evaluate is too long 3) your string passed to [...] is wrong: it must be built just as you would type it into a cell (to build a string use `Worksheet.Evaluate` rather than `[...]` ) 4) you can't create a workbook reference to a closed workbook (`Set wbk = ...` won't work) 5) `wbk.wks.Range` is wrong: should be just `wks.Range` (only if the references work, which they don't, see point 4) 6) you can't do `Range(...).End(xlUp)` on a closed workbook

Comment: Thanks, I’ll rework based on your comments. These pointers are really appreciated, as I’ve just been trying to take a guess at the moment. Any recommendations for reading/tutorials on this sort of thing is really welcome as I’m really interested in learning.

Comment: Couple of good places: cpearson.com decisionmodels.com rondebruin.nl and others.